# How do I call a method from the main method?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I have a method that creates a mapping which associates the same value for each key.  How do I call that method from my main method?

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> str1(String[] strings) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap();
    for (String s:strings) {
        map.put(s, 1);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain exactly what problem you are having calling that method.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  I cleaned up your code/question formatting a bit and provided an answer.  In the future, please try to be more verbose.  Post the full minimum reproducible issue; e.e. your class definition and error message and the failing function would be great.

Comment: This is a great forum, but you need to try hard to make good question content so you get good answers.  Try to add more above to avoid getting the question closed, and to train yourself for next time around!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was actually a coding learning website that I was trying answer a coding problem. Here is the problem "https://codingbat.com/prob/p152303".

Comment: Given an array of strings, return a Map<String, Integer> containing a key for every different string in the array, always with the value 0. For example the string "hello" makes the pair "hello":0. 


word0(["a", "b", "a", "b"]) → {"a": 0, "b": 0}
word0(["a", "b", "a", "c", "b"]) → {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0}
word0(["c", "b", "a"]) → {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0}

Answer (score 0):

In Java, this would be a "member function".  So, you would have to create an instance of your object that has that main function, and then call it on that.

Alternatively, you can make this a static function and call it from `main()` itself, which is a bit easier for simple apps.

Here's an example of a full class the static way:

```
public class MyClass {

    private static String [] keys = { "cat", "dog" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> result = str1(keys);
    }

    public static HashMap<String, Integer> str1(String[] strings) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap();
        for (String s:strings) {
            map.put(s, 1);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

To do it without "static" on your function, you would have to do something like this in main to create an instance of MyClass:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Create instance of class.
    MyClass c = new MyClass(); 

    //Call the str1 member function on this class instance.
    HashMap<String, Integer> results = c.str1(keys);
}
```